# How to get links not from a website using php and regular expression

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink, nofollow

I want to add rel="nofollow" in all links in my website if the links link to other website.

For example,

```
$str = "<a href='www.linktoothersite.com'>I swear this isn't spam!</a><br><a href='www.mywebsite.com'>Hello World</a>";
```

The output should be

```
$str = "<a href='www.linktoothersite.com' rel="nofollow">I swear this isn't spam!</a><br><a href='www.mywebsite.com'>Hello World</a>";
```

**I really want to regular expression but not DDOMDocument. Because when I using DOMDocument I always got error "
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity"**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I programmatically add rel="external" to external links in a string of HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608874/how-do-i-programmatically-add-rel-external-to-external-links-in-a-string-of-htm)

Comment: don't parse html with regex. use DOMDocument instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a DOM parser and loop over all the links, checking their `href` attribute for other sites.  This is untested and might require some tweaking.

```
// assuming your html is in $HTMLstring
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($HTMLstring);

// May need to disable error checking if the HTML isn't fully valid
$dom->strictErrorChecking = FALSE;

// Get all the links
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName("a");
foreach($links as $link) {
  $href = $link->getAttribute("href");

  // Find out if the link points to a domain other than yours
  // If your internal links are relative, you'll have to do something fancier to check
  // their destinations than this simple strpos()
  if (strpos("yourdomain.example.com", $href) == -1) {
     // Add the attribute
     $link->setAttribute("rel", "nofollow");
  }

// Save the html
$output = $dom->saveHTML;
```

Comment: I always got 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity,  when I using $dom->loadHTML. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like you're handing it invalid HTML, missing the semicolon on an entity like `&amp` somewhere.  Either make sure the HTML is valid, or also try setting `$dom->strictErrorChecking = FALSE` so it overlooks more of those problems.